# Save Multiple Checkbox into MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i already saw other pages about this topic, but i can't find the solution for my case.

I have a form with almost 70 fields, and 3 of them are Checkbox where the user can choose more than one option and i need to save them all.

I know that probably thats an easy way to resolve this but i'm about 8 hours straight and i can't see nothing at this point...

HTML Form:

```
(...)

<p><b>Quais as empresas que reconhece como patrocinadores desta edição da prova?</b></p>                               
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="EDP"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>EDP<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Agência Abreu"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Agência Abreu<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="DietSport"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>DietSport<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Dolce Vita Douro"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Dolce Vita Douro<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Europcar"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Europcar<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Fruut"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Fruut<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Jumbo"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Jumbo<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Liberty Seguros"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Liberty Seguros<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Reccua"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Reccua<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Vindimar"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Vindimar<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Vitalis"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Vitalis<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Patrocinadores_Prova" value="Wall Street English"><span style="padding-left:10px"></span>Wall Street English<br><br>                               


(...)
```

PHP Code:

```
(...)

$Patrocinadores_Prova      = $_POST['Patrocinadores_Prova'];

(...)

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO questionario(...'" . implode(',', $Patrocinadores_Prova) ."'....)
```

Comment: what does `var_dump` on `$p_test` say and whats your checkbox HTML?

Comment: Checkbox data does not get POST'ed unless the checkbox is checked. I would expect to see some testing to see if the $_POST variables exist before doing anything with the data. So where is that code?

Comment: @Felk, see the code pls.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, see the code pls.

Comment: Ignore the previous code. I'm using the code above.

Comment: Still no `var_dump`. Also, as RiggsFolly said, the variable is empty, if no checkbox is selected.

Comment: if you change the name to 'array' format, name="Patrocinadores_Prova[]", at least all the values of the  'checked' ones will appear in $_POST.

Comment: @RyanVincent, yes, i'm trying that solution. When i call them and echo, its fine. When i adapt the code to my original file, gives me [04-Jun-2014 19:16:25 Europe/Lisbon] PHP Warning:  array_map() [<a href='function.array-map'>function.array-map</a>]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/meiamara/public_html/submeter_form.php on line 29
[04-Jun-2014 19:16:25 Europe/Lisbon] PHP Warning:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/meiamara/public_html/submeter_form.php on line 29

Comment: That `implode(',', $Patrocinadores_Prova)` won work. Remember the fields will only exists in $_POST if the user checks the box. So if you have a field list in `INSERT INTO questionario(...` you will be missing stuff in the data part. SHOW ALL THE CODE!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to save multiple check boxes value in database you have to use array[], so first change your chackboxes name from  name="Patrocinadores_Prova" to  name="Patrocinadores_Prova[]" and then execute your php code.